# .htaccess - how to rewrite a query at the end of any URL to a clean URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I feel like I've tried everything to do a fairly simple rewrite and I just can't get it working! I'm really no expert with htaccess though.

Say my URL is `example.com/setup/` and I have a slightly modified version of the same page at `example.com/setup/?cloud=true`

I need this modified version of the page to be accessible at `example.com/setup/cloud/`

It needs to be an actual rule (as opposed to just a straight 1 for 1 rewrite) as this pattern is used throughout the website.

Basically, if `?cloud=true` is on the end of the URL, that page needs to be accessible at the exact same URL, but with `/cloud/` at the end instead of `?cloud=true`

Here's what I think is the closest I've gotten to a correct rule, may still be way off though:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)/cloud$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?cloud=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following ruleset should achieve the intended:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.+)\?(cloud)=true
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cloud=true$
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)/cloud/?$ /$1?cloud=true [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you! I have tried so many combinations, pasted this in and it worked perfectly first time.

Will accept as the correct answer once it allows me to. :)